# Custom grid / graticule in openlayers v6

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to add a grid to my map (just like the graticule) using distances between lines and I would like the line labels to stay at the same position and have the grid updated on view change.

I am listening to prerender events on a vector layer and drawing from the `CanvasImmediateRenderer` returned by `getVectorContext(event);` and I have been unsuccesful at keeping the labels sticking to the top and left borders.

Any help is very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: VectorContext seems the right approach.  What is the problem with labels?

Comment: @mike I have added the code for the vector layer approach

Comment: It looks like line placement of text does not work well with immediate rendering.  Separate Point drawings for the labels would be better, you could use `view.calculateExtent()` or `event.framestate.extent` to determine the left or top coordinates.  Use a separate style for top and side labels, `textAlign` 'left' or 'right' as appropriate and a Math.PI/4 rotation for the top labels.

Comment: Thank you mike, it'sa good idea  I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: @mike, since I have a hold an openlayer expert, my design has 2 undesired behavior: 
 - The grid is only drawn on one "world", is there a way to draw it on every world or should I constrain the view ?
- The grid is not drawn when there is no render event (when there is no feature drawn) is there a way to force render or any other suggestion ? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like line placement of text does not work well with immediate rendering. Separate Point drawings for the labels would be better, you could use `event.framestate.extent` to determine the left or top coordinates.

Use a separate style for top and side labels, `textAlign` `'left'` or '`right'` as appropriate and a Math.PI/2 rotation for the top labels.

To force rendering for the grid use a dedicated layer with one barely visible feature and an infinite renderBuffer like so :

```js
let grid = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
      features: [new Feature(new Point([0,0]))]
  }),
  style: new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 0
      })
  }),
  renderBuffer: Infinity,
});

// Listen to prerender event to render the grid
grid.on('prerender', function(event: RenderEvent) {

  let unitSplit = .1; // every .1 m
  let pxToUnit = view.getResolution();
  let pxSplit = unitSplit / pxToUnit;

  let [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = event.frameState.extent

  while (pxSplit * 2 < 100) {
    unitSplit *= 2;
    pxSplit = unitSplit / pxToUnit; // distance between two lines
  }

  let startX = Math.round(xmin / unitSplit) * unitSplit; // first line
  let endX = Math.round(xmax / unitSplit) * unitSplit; // last line

  let startY = Math.round(ymin / unitSplit) * unitSplit;
  let endY = Math.round(ymax / unitSplit) * unitSplit;

  let ctx = getVectorContext(event);

  let lineStyle = new Style({ stroke: new Stroke({ color: "#444751", width: 1 }) });
  ctx.setStyle(lineStyle);

  // drawing lines
  for (let i = startX; i <= endX; i = i + unitSplit) {
    ctx.drawLineString(new LineString([[i, ymin], [i, ymax]])); // draw
  }


  for (let i = startY; i <= endY; i = i + unitSplit) {
    ctx.drawLineString(new LineString([[xmin, i], [xmax, i]]));
  }

  let text = new Text({ fill: new Fill({ color: "#ffffff" }), font: "12px arial", textAlign: "left" })

  // drawing labels
  for (let i = startY; i <= endY; i = i + unitSplit) {
    text.setText(`${(i / 1000).toFixed(2)} km`);
    lineStyle.setText(text)
    ctx.setStyle(lineStyle);
    ctx.drawPoint(new Point([event.frameState.extent[0] + 10 * pxToUnit, i + pxToUnit]))

  }

  text.setRotation(Math.PI / 2)

  for (let i = startX; i <= endX; i = i + unitSplit) {
    text.setText(`${(i / 1000).toFixed(2)} km`);
    lineStyle.setText(text)
    ctx.setStyle(lineStyle);
    ctx.drawPoint(new Point([i + pxToUnit, event.frameState.extent[3] - 10 * pxToUnit]))

  }
}
```

Comment: I came around the wrapping issue, thanks to your previous comment but I might have missed something about the additional vector layer, it does not work for me.

Comment: Are you using the prerender event for that layer, and is it added to the map?

Comment: forgot to listen on this layer ................... You are a true genius ‍